# Embedding SDL into GTK+

Tags: c, sdl, gtk

I have an application that uses GTK+ to display some nice GUI, but I am using SDL to display a small RGB frame buffer inside GTK+

I have used the following code to get SDL into GTK+:

```
char SDL_windowhack[32];
sprintf(SDL_windowhack, "SDL_WINDOWID=%ld", GDK_WINDOW_XWINDOW(deviceWindow->window));
putenv(SDL_windowhack);
```

Unfortunately, I also use SDL for keyboard and mouse event. The main thread that uses SDL to update the image spawns the following thread:

```
void *SDLEvent(void *arg)
{
    SDL_Event event;

    while (1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Test\n");
        SDL_WaitEvent(&event);
        switch (event.type) {
            /* ... */
        }
    }
}
```

I see that the print statement is executed twice, then none. As soon as I terminate the thread that SDL uses to update the screen (display), the loop in SDLEvent starts executing very fast again.

This code used to work fine before I integrated SDL into GTK+ so I am thinking GTK+ is maybe blocking SDL in some ways?

Does anyone have any suggestions please?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although I have not used SDL, but as you are looking for events it appears that you are running two event loops. Gtk runs its own event loop which handles events like the ones from mouse & keyboard. I think you need to find a way to integrate the both. Some googling resulted in the following [link](http://sdl.beuc.net/sdl.wiki/FAQ_GUI) where in the section "Double event loop issue" your problem has been addressed (I think). Try adding `SDLEvent` function as idler function using [`g_idle_add`](http://developer.gnome.org/glib/unstable/glib-The-Main-Event-Loop.html#g-idle-add) as suggested in the [link](http://sdl.beuc.net/sdl.wiki/FAQ_GUI) and see if it works.
Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, that look like an awesome solution! It's not working yet quite  but I'll fiddle with it, thanks a lot!

Comment: I am using "The SDL_WINDOWID hack" on the link you gave me. I just saw: "You do not receive the usual SDL events for this solution.". I guess I am unlucky :(

Comment: @Jary: Hmmm that bad. Can't you use keyboard and mouse events from Gtk event loop?

Comment: Yes I can, but I have a downside. It involves some re-writing. The major problem is for mouse event: SDL was it's own window, when a mouse click happened I knew I could read off the x and y values directly.With GTK, I will have to make sure I am inside the SDL window, and do some extra computation to figure out the x and y values as if I was only inside the SDL window. That is the major hurdle, getting the x-y values in relation to the SDL window.